# Passing button value for a dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, html

I have elements that are dynamically created. But I can't seem to add a onclick event that passes down the buttons own value. The function itself is not being called.

```
var btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.innerHTML = "Edit";
            btn.value = i;
            btn.onclick ="EditData(this.value)"; // <---- 

function EditData(value) {
    alert(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the function itself:

```
var btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.innerHTML = "Edit";
            btn.value = '2';
            btn.onclick = EditData;

function EditData(event) {
    alert(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign a **function** to [**`onclick`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick), not a **string**:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  EditData(this.value);
};
```

Maybe you thought you had to assign a string, because in HTML we would write

```
onclick="...."
```

However, the DOM API is different from HTML.

[Learn more about events and different ways to bind handlers.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)